# Чем описание объектов в applicationContext Spring лучше кода Java

Tags: java, spring

Начал знакомство с фреймворком Spring и встал вопрос. Если мы описываем те же самые зависимости в файле "applicationContext" между классами, то чем же лучше Spring по сравнению с обычным подходом. Может я еще новичок. но мне не кажется читать код в виде java легче чем в описание зависимостей и бинов в файле "applicationContext"

Comment: Spring Boot-ом как минимум лучше.

Comment: @AntonSorokin, аргументируйте, чем лучше и почему. А то, как минимум непонятно с чего вы так решили?

Comment: Я черпаю информацию с форумов, видеоуроков, говорят что популярен.

Comment: @And потому что Spring Framework выполняет много рутинной работы, которую пришлось бы выполнять разработчику + приносит некоторые "технологии", например IoC, которые упрощают жизнь разработчику.

А Spring Boot убирает рутинные действия которые разработчику пришлось бы выполнять при работе со спрингом, например та же работа с контекстом.

Comment: @АлексейСемёнов скорее всего вы получаете устаревшую информацию. Она правильная, и возможно пригодится, но в минимальном количестве случаев. Лучше откройте какую нибудь книгу по спрингу и почитайте. Книгу можно найти в гугле.

Comment: @АлексейСемёнов, Я знаю, просто некоторые пользователи, которые зайдут в тему и увидят слово "лучше", не поймут чем и о чем речь, по этому лучше впредь, аргументировать или хотя-бы, намекать.

Comment: Если приложение по сложности рядом с hello world, то однозначно хуже

Comment: @AntonSorokin что-то Вы оперирует какими-то непонятными терминами "рутинная работа", "рутинные действия". Думаю не каждый поймет, что Вы имеете ввиду

Comment: Вы читаете плохие форумы / смотрите плохие видеоуроки. В хорошей книге Spring in Action автор говорит, что Java и XML конфигурация это дело вкуса, но большинство предпочитают Java (хотя бы потому что в современных средах разработки типа Intellij IDEA, Eclipse есть code completion, чего нету в xml + в xml Вы пишите строки и можете просто сделать опечатку, которую не подскажет среда и при запуске приложения получите невнятную ошибку).

Comment: @notaProgrammer а еще xml конфигурация просто сложнее и непонятнее